# Quantum gis 2.2 - pasting templates

Tags: geometry, circle, template

Is there a way to paste geometries in a workspace at the location i want? e.g. i want to paste a circle from another workspace in the workspace i'm working with. I need only the geometry, not the coordinates.

Comment: I guess your circle is a polygon (buffer from a point for instance). If it is the case, a simple *Copy feature* from layer 1 followed by a *Paste features* on layer 2 should do the job, assuming that both layers have the same CRS.

Comment: yes, my circle is a polygon. using the copy feature let me paste the polygon at the same coordinates. what i want is to paste the polygon at an other coordinate.

Comment: Then, paste your circle and then use the **Move Feature(s)** button to displace your circle to the right place...